# Matlab's filter in Java

Tags: java, matlab

I am trying to implement in java Matlab's function "filter" in Java.

```
Y = FILTER(B,A,X)
```

It says that :  The filter is a "Direct Form II Transposed" implementation of the standard difference equation:

```
 a(1)*y(n) = b(1)*x(n) + b(2)*x(n-1) + ... + b(nb+1)*x(n-nb)
                         - a(2)*y(n-1) - ... - a(na+1)*y(n-na)
```

Can somebody help me with that as I don't really understand the above formula. Can somebody show me an example of the above formula using these parameters:

e.g. `filter([1 -1],[1 -hpf_pole],S')`

where hpf_pole = 0.98

S =

```
-3.26368263029463   0.598694437762099   0.925551549649237
-3.15561902947223   0.00249461257261130 2.35703360665011
-2.89398994439634   1.98384531062216    3.67478741307554
```

Comment: There is a diagram of the filter on that help page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read about [Direct Form II Transposed](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/fp/Transposed_Direct_Forms.html). But it's useful to read more about [Direct Forms](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/fp/Four_Direct_Forms.html) and [Implementation of discrete transfer functions](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/fp/Implementation_Structures_Recursive_Digital.html) in general to know why it's useful and when to use it.

Answer (score 0):

OK I implemented something in Java that looks like it is doing the job:

```
   public void filter(){
         double hpfPole = 0.98;
         double[] b = new double[]{1,-1};
         double[] a = new double[]{1, -hpfPole};
         double[] x = new double[]{-7.3416, -7.3416, -7.3416};
         double[] y = new double[x.length];

         for (int n = 0; n < y.length; n++) {
             if(n-1 < 0){
                 y[n] = b[0]*x[n];
             }else{
                y[n]= b[0]*x[n]+b[1]*x[n-1]-a[1]*y[n-1]; 
             }

         }


     }
```

> ```
> Input: -7.3416, -7.3416, -7.3416
> Output: -7.3416, -7.194768, -7.05087264
> ```

Answer (score 0):

More generally it would be something like:

```
public double[] filter(double[] b, double[] a, double[] x) {
    int nx = x.length;
    int na = a.length;
    int nb = b.length;

    double[] y = new double[nx];
    for (int k = 0; k < nx; k++) {
        y[k] = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < nb; i++) {
            if (k - i >= 0 && k - i < nx) {
                y[k] += b[i] * x[k - i];
            }
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < na; i++) {
            if (k - i >= 0 && k - i < nx) {
                y[k] -= a[i] * y[k - i];
            }
        }
        if (Math.abs(a[0] - 1) > 1.e-9) {
            y[k] /= a[0];
        }

    }
    return y;
}
```